# How can you find out which object a value belongs to?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, trace

Say I have a dictionary called dic:

```
dic = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

And let's say I have some code, and later on, I provide the key dic["a"] to derive a value 1. How would I be able to inform the programme that the value 1 came from the key of "a" inside "dic", and not from say, a list, or another dic, and so on?

This is important because am writing a programme where there are many of the same values, but parts of the programme are going to run based upon where the value came from.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you're going about things wrong. Why do you care that it came from a dictionary from a certain key? To take your question literally, I don't believe there is a way unless you manually track such a relationship. If you give broader context though, we may be able to help you out. Specifically why "parts of the programme are going to run based upon where the value came from"?

Comment: Well it's a little bit hard to explain but OK. Basically am making a financial "app" (for what is probably for lack of a better term) for myself, and I have a class called finances with certain methods. I've split my finances into various sources, so there's emergency funds, savings, etc. If a certain source is overdrawn, it will attempt to withdraw funds from other sources, and depending upon what source is drawing upon what, that will determine the type of activity that will occur.

Comment: There's more to it than that, but I guess you just got to believe me when I say that the solution in my mind is the most elegant one I can come up with, only I don't know how to implement that solution.

Comment: You'll need to store the "source" information with the data manually. A simple way would be to store a string like "savings" or "chequing" with the number. You could have a class or just use a tuple like `(123, "savings")`, or a dictionary like `{"amount": 123, "source": "savings"}`. There's no way to have this information automatically like you're asking, so you'll need to go for an alternative approach.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Yeah, I guess I'll just have to use an additional argument that notifies the program where the value is being derived from. I know that that's a solution, but I was hoping it wouldn't come to that. I am surprised there's nothing in the introspect/sys/traceback module, but it seems like there's no other way.

Comment: There would be too many weird corner cases. Like, if you retrieved the data via `dic["a"]`, then passed the data through a function, did the data come from the function, or a certain key in the dictionary? What if you used `get` instead of `[]` in the same scenario? Would the data have been from the first call to `get`, or from the second function that the data was passed to, and how you you differentiate those cases? Even if there was a way, it would be significantly cleaner and less painful to just manually record that information.

Comment: you could consider your withdraw / transfer as a transaction which holds info like money, source, destination etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is, as far as I know, no way to do what you're asking. Data retrieved from dictionaries and other sources have no knowledge of the key that they were associated with originally.

I think the cleanest method would be to have some kind of wrapper function that handles this for you and stores the data in an easy to use format:

```
from typing import Dict, NamedTuple

class Record(NamedTuple):
    amount: int
    source: str

def recording_get(dict: Dict[str, int], source: str) -> Record:
    return Record(dict[source], source)


dic = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
rec = recording_get(dic, "a")
print(rec)  #  Prints Record(amount=1, source='a')
```